# Dart method has errors but does not return error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking at the flutter firebase auth docs.

Specifically, I am looking at [these docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html), for the method FirebaseAuth.createUserFromEmailAndPassword.

In the docs it lists three errors. But I am confused as to how these errors get communicated back to the caller. It gives no information on the types of these errors. I am really confused here. If it doesn't return an error type, and it doesn't take an error out parameter as an input, how is this method supposed to communicate errors?

Apparently there are three errors just floating in the ether that I can not get a hold of lol.

Answer (score 1):

The method will throw an [`AuthException`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/AuthException-class.html). The exception will have a `code` field. The contents of the code field will explain what went wrong exactly.

> - ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD - If the password is not strong enough.
> - ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL - If the email address is malformed.
> - ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE - If the email is already in use by a
>     different account.

You can handle these errors like any other exception in Dart: with a try/catch.

```dart
try {
  var result = await FirebaseAuth.createUserFromEmailAndPassword(...);
} catch (e) {
  if (e is AuthException) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD':
        // Handle weak password
        break;
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
        // Handle invalid email
        break;
      case 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE':
        // Handle email in use
        break;
    }
  } else {
    // An error other than an AuthException was thrown
  }
}
```

Comment: @ScottF By perusing the documentation and by asserting that if it doesn't return the errors in the `AuthResult` object and there isn't a global `error` object in the package (which would be _very_ non-idiomatic for Dart anyway; this isn't C) that leaves only one logical conclusion: they are thrown.

Comment: @ScottF An educated guess, based on the information in the docs and experience on how these things are typically handled. If you really want to know for sure, set up a test app and try it yourself. (That would be much faster than posting an SO question and waiting for an answer anyway,)

Comment: Can you give a complete example of how handling these errors would look in code?

Comment: @ScottF I'll show you, but to be completely and brutally honest, and I mean no offense, but if you don't know how to do that, you need to read some more Dart tutorials and get a firmer grasp of the basics of the language.

Comment: @ScottF Whatever you say bro.